# How to display parent view table view above suddenly upon child view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, childviewcontroller, rootviewcontroller

This is my window hierarchy

```
->Root view Controller
                    ->tableview
    -> child view controller 1

      ->child view controller 2
```

Image specification :
[image]

[image]

first image `**Rootview**` `controller` ,second image is child view `controller` placed ,because of child view my `root view controller` has been hidden ,how i have to make the `**tableview**` as super view.

In root view controller i have `**tableview**` when user clicks navigation bar button i need to show it on above two child view `controller` is it possible ?

This is my code its presents on **`RootViewController`**

```
- (IBAction)tableviewapicall:(id)sender
{
    if(tableviewbool)
    {
        _tableview.hidden=NO;
        tableviewbool=NO;
        [_tableview superview];
    }
    else
    {
        _tableview.hidden=YES;
        tableviewbool=YES;
    }
}
```

Please help me to do that friends:)

Comment: i have tried to place the tableview to superview but can't bro ,so i decide to ask question for better solution @user6April

Comment: Yes it is possible to push or present `rootViewController` . You should post your code and error you get.

Comment: ok @user6April i will update my question with in 5 minutes

Comment: @user6April that above one is my code.

Answer (score 1):

**To implement this Simply try this steps:**

First give tag to both Child view controller View.

Let say if you have child view controller in Storyboard or xib than just give unique tag to it.

If you have created child view controller programmatically than assign tag programmatically there.

Now simply do this:

```
- (IBAction)tableviewapicall:(id)sender {
    if(tableviewbool) {
        _tableview.hidden=NO;
        tableviewbool=NO;
        [_tableview superview];
        // Get both Child view controller view by tag Hide it
    } else {
        _tableview.hidden=YES;
        tableviewbool=YES;
        // Get both Child view controller view by tag Show it
    }
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: in my method i need to display home screen don't want to hide ,if i have that option then your idea will be correct :).